# Android Google map add custom place

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I want to add a custom place on google map. I am using map API v2 .. I just want to achieve the functionality like default maps application in android in which user can add any place anywhere on map and can add any description title etc for that place.. I look around for solutions but didn't find it. Any help with be appreciated...

Comment: Searching in google for your title, I find a lot of useful-looking links - what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't want to add only custom markers etc i want to make change in map that should be visible to all on any device and in any application

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want a google maps api that allows you to do permanent edits?

Comment: Yes exactly.........

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a small question don't put basic things in here. First, you have to search your requirement and if you not found put question here.
These provide basic knowledge about google map http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/custom-marker-icon-for-google-maps-android-api-v2/ If you need to touch the map and add marker you can refer this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-marker-on-touched-location-of-google-maps-using-android-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/ hope these links work for you.

Comment: Brother actually i want to edit map not want to add custom marker. if i add custom marker then that marker will be visible to only that app. i want to add marker on google map that should add on map permanently and be visible on map when user open the map from any device

Comment: I don't think is it available.So far from my knowledge goggle not support to edit their map to user.